When you open a sqlite database, the db size changes
I am developing an app with flutter. Use sqlite db using sqflite.
await downloadDB(appDocumentsDir.path}/$dbFileName);  //DB Size 30236672
//DB open
 Database database = await openDatabase("${appDocumentsDir.path}/$dbFileName"); //DB Size 30240768

When you open it as written above, the size of the DB changes. This only happens on android.
As data is added, the length of the DB increases, which causes validation using CheckSum to fail. Why does this only happen on Android?

See here
The "android_metadata" table is automatically created and its size increases. If the "android_metadata" table exists, it is not created. If not, it is created. As in the link above, android_metadata was created in advance to ensure consistency.
